# Cannot log in onto Django Admin Panel with a custom user

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I created a custom user model shown below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.model(username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **kwargs):
        user = self.create_user(username,password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


class tgUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)                                
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} ({self.last_name})"
```

In the settings.py, I specified:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "table.TgUser" 
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
# ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
```

Yet the admin panel still displays "Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." on login.

How can I solve this?

---

Update: As @AbdulAzizBarkat suggested, I tried adding a @property for is_staff or even a whole custom BaseUserAdmin class. That didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: You don't have any `is_staff` field on your custom model. The admin site uses that for authorization. Also instead of `is_admin` it is supposed to be `is_superuser`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I added ```is_staff``` field, but it doesn't resolve the issue. I also tried with ```is_superuser``` - no result.

Comment: How do you create your user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django admin not working with custom user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009015/django-admin-not-working-with-custom-user)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ```python3 manager.py createsuperuser```
Then:
```
Username: admin
Password: 
Password (again): 
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
This password is entirely numeric.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.
```

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' in settings.py already

Comment: `makesuperuser`? Do you mean `createsuperuser`? Also there's no answer on that question asking you to add that, please read the answers properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245666/discussion-between-pylyr-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with **kwargs. You must always include them. Below is a working implementation.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(username, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, username, password, **other_fields):

        user = self.model(username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```